# Argument for ProcessStartInfo needs quotes, always escapes

Tags: c#, process, processstartinfo

If I run the following command in a command prompt, it works:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AppFolder\do.exe"
```

If I try to run the same thing as a process:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @"/c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\AppFolder\do.exe""";

        using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
          ...
        }
```

It does not appear to run. If I look at the startInfo.Arguments, it appears as follows:

```
/c \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AppFolder\\do.exe\"
```

What am I missing? Can you not pass arguments that have quotes or spaces? I see a lot of examples where people are passing items with spaces/quotes in just fine, but following them just doesn't seem to work. This is the narrowest example I can think of.

EDIT: If I just create a shortcut so I don't use spaces or quotes, it works:

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/c D:\_test\Do.lnk";
```

Comment: _It does not appear to run._ How does it not appear to run? Try to remove the hidden window style and change the `/c` option to a `/k` option. I bet you will see an error message in the console window that now lingers.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use '@'. This is correct implementation:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AppFolder\\do.exe\"";
```

Comment: `"/c \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AppFolder\\do.exe\""` is exactly the same string as `@"/c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\AppFolder\do.exe"""`. How you escape the backslashes and quotes does not make a difference.